# Is using AnimatedOpacity to hide and show complex widgets not effective in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm using `AnimatedOpacity` to hide some widgets in `Stack` between various states in my app.

For instance I have `Stack` with `ListView` and animating loading indicator (*shimmer*) below, so that when list is populated the animated background opacity is gradually set to 0.

```
Stack:
 - AnimatedOpacity (
      opacity: _populated ? 0.0 : 1.0, 
      child: AnimatedLoadingWidget,
   ),
 - ListView
```

Do I understand correctly that the animation in AnimatedLoadingWidget continues and is rendered even if opacity is set to 0.0? Does it have a performance impact on the app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're wondering whether or not the widget is still rendered when an opacity of 0, then **no**.

`Opacity` and its animated variant is clever enough to *not* render the child if the opacity is strictly equal to 0.

But that's not enough. Even with an opacity of 0, your loading widget is still in the widget tree, and its animation continues to play.

To be more specific, with typical:

```dart
Opacity(
  opacity: 0,
  child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
)
```

the spinner will not be visible, but it will still endlessly request new frames.

To fix that, we can use `TickerMode` widget like so:

```dart
Opacity(
  opacity: 0,
  child: TickerMode(
    enabled: false,
    child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
)
```

Doing so will "mute" animations played using the animation framework, and as such, the spinner will stop requesting for new frames.

Alternatively, you can use `AnimatedCrossFade` with a custom `layoutBuilder` to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I did not know about `TickerMode` widget :)

Comment: Can we always use this `TickerMode` widget for any kind of child no matter if they use SingleTickerProvider or similar mixins just to be sure they consume less resources when opacity is equal to 0? For instance I use a `VideoPlayer` widget and I have a `AnimatedOpacity` wrapping it. Should I use `TickerMode`?